# Showing 404 error when a cookie is not set

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.2

I think the title is clear; I want to create a rule on web-server that if a user tries to reach specific path like `http://mysite.com/admin` face the 404 error, while this folder is available and contains files. If my cookie is set on the client's system, he/she can visit that path.

I'm looking for a `.htaccess` solution, but any other answers (php or anything) are appreciated too.

I'm not familiar with writing rewrite rules but [this](http://emanipur.org/blog/item/134-how-to-change-your-joomla-admin-folder-name) may help:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !myCookie=9856012345
RewriteRule .* - [L,F]
```

It shows 403 error, and people will know that the path exists, I want them to feel there's no such path on the folder by showing 404 error.

Comment: This does not look like a very high level security scheme... I suppose you know. That being said, I like the idea of a 404 instead of 403 (or 401). I do that in some circumstances too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a 404 redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !myCookie=9856012345
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```